# Can't read cookie in Nest.js that deployed vercel

Tags: cookies, next.js, cors, nestjs, vercel

I'm developing some Nest.js server and i deployed this app. But when i deploy it on vercel. I met some problem. I can't read cookies from my request.

**vercel.json**

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "name": "myapi",
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "src/main.ts",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/src/main.ts",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"],
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://example.com",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version"
      }
    }
  ],
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "https://example.com" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors({
    credentials: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PATCH', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    origin: [
      'https://example.com',
      'http:example.com',
      '*',
    ],
  });
  app.use(cookieParser());
  await app.listen(8000);
}

bootstrap();
```

**auth.gaurd.ts**

```
import {
  CanActivate,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { Request } from 'express';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private configService: ConfigService,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
  ) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const token = this.extractTokenFromHeader(request);
    if (!token) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    try {
      const payload = await this.jwtService.verifyAsync(token, {
        secret: this.configService.get('JWT_SECRET'),
      });
      request['my-app'] = payload;
    } catch {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return true;
  }

  private extractTokenFromHeader(request: Request): string | undefined {
    return request.cookies['my-app'];
  }
}
```

**my.client.app.js (I have some problem with set cookie in vercel server so i did like it)**

```
cookies.set("example", data.token, {
        sameSite: "none",
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000,
        httpOnly: true,
        path: "/",
        secure: true,
        domain: ".example.com",
      });
```

**My fetch function**

```
const response = await fetch(`${SERVER_URL}/auth`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        credentials: "include",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: emailInputElement.value,
          password: passwordInputElement.value,
        }),
      });
```

How can i read cookie in Nest.js deployed in vercel? In development, it was worked. I read amount of article but nothing changed. I've try to solve this problem all my hours 3 day, but i cant... Somebody help me!

- I deployed my front web site (Next.js) vercel too!!

I try everything that i find.... But there are so few amount of article....

Comment: What are the Web origins of your backend and frontend?